# Windows 7 hangs up after Ubuntu dual-boot installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 using the Linux Live USB creator to create a live USB and then booting/installing from that drive.

Everything seemed to go smoothly.  I first tested booting Ubuntu from grub  and everything seems fine with the new installation.

My problem is that there are 3 options (although 2 say recovery partition) that have "Windows" associated with them.  Only one when I select it shows the "Starting Windows" screen where the Windows 7 logo would normally appear after an animation.  At this point after waiting for extended periods of time, nothing further happens.

(If you need any more information I will update this and provide it.  I'm a beginner with Linux but I'll do my best to help!)

Comment: May be, some windows boot files are corrupted. u can try this [link](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/681-startup-repair.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve ur problem u need to first repair the windows boot loader and after that reinstalling the grub2 after that u can dual boot both the os

> for windows boot loader repair

=> u need a windows 7 repair disc or windows 7 live usb or live cd

boot from any of the above windows disc and go to repair but not to use startup repair instead repair using windows command prompt

type the following two commands in cmd exactly

Bootrec/fixmbr 'press enter'

Bootrec/fixboot 'press enter'

now reboot u can see windows boot loader again

> now to repair grub boot loader

=> u need ubuntu live usb and use " load ubuntu without install" then install boot-repair and repair grub u can see it in this how it is done https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

if u install windows boot loader u can create a ubutnu live usb in windows using unetbootin(in case if u have a single pendrive currently)

i hope this will solve ur problem