# Classpnp.sys causes windows to hang after ubuntu install

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-7, uefi

I have looked far and wide for a solution to this problem. I have tried many options from boot-repair, bootrec in windows and I still can't resolve it. 
The problem is that windows will boot when in legacy mode but hangs when in UEFI - it hangs at classpnp.sys. Now, the grub menu will not load when in legacy mode so I cannot get into ubuntu. I can see the grub menu when booting in UEFI mode but on selecting the windows boot loader, it runs until classpnp.sys. The only option I have at the moment to switch between linux and windows is changing between legacy and UEFI. 
I know there are many posts similar to this so apologies for bringing it back up - it's a big frustration. I have tried this [Windows 7 hangs up after Ubuntu dual-boot installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430129/windows-7-hangs-up-after-ubuntu-dual-boot-installation) to no avail. Any ideas would be very welcome.

Many thanks,
MRF

Ps. I know it isn't a classpnp.sys problem as that is the last thing it loads. Interestingly I ran safe mode in legacy (when windows does start) and no other drivers are loaded after classpnp.sys as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Most OS installations, including Windows, are made in one boot mode (BIOS/CSM/legacy or EFI/UEFI). Switching to another boot mode requires installing a new boot loader, and often changing the partition table type (MBR to GPT or vice-versa). Switching quickly from one boot mode to another is possible with Linux, which is pretty flexible; but I've never heard of successful dynamic boot-mode switching with Windows.

A second issue to consider is that it's almost always best to coordinate boot modes across OSes. That is, if Windows is configured to boot in EFI mode, you should install Linux in EFI mode too; and if Windows is in BIOS mode, you should install Linux in BIOS mode, too. Doing otherwise is possible, but requires extra hoop-jumping.

In most cases, Windows is the first OS installed on a computer. Thus, you should determine the Windows boot mode. This is normally tied to the partition table type: The Windows BIOS-mode boot loader understands MBR but not GPT, and the Windows EFI-mode boot loader likes to see GPT. You can easily check your partition table type in Linux:

```
$ sudo parted -l | grep Table
Partition Table: gpt
```

If you get several lines of output, that means you've got several disks. (Removable disks count, so remove them first.) A GPT disk shows up as being of type `gpt` and an MBR disk shows up as of type `msdos`. Using this information, you should know how Windows should be booting. If you've got multiple disks and they're of different types, you'll need to figure out the type of the *Windows boot disk.*

If you've installed Linux in the wrong mode, the solution is to install an appropriate boot loader for Linux. It sounds like you've got a BIOS-mode Windows install but you've managed to convince Ubuntu to install in EFI mode. (This requires some tenacity, but can be done.) If so, you should install the `grub-pc` package, which will replace `grub-efi`, then run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` to install GRUB. You may also need to do an `update-grub`. Alternatively, the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) program should do this all automatically, but you must run it from the proper boot mode, which may mean booting an emergency disk in the right boot mode.

If you run `parted` and find that your partition table type is GPT rather than MBR, then something else is going on -- chances are GRUB has misidentified your Windows boot loader. In this case, I'd need more information to offer a specific suggestion for a repair. The `RESULTS.txt` file generated by [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) would be helpful. Post it to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here.

---

**EDIT:**

Based on your Boot Info Script output, you've got a GPT disk, and there's no evidence of any BIOS-mode Windows boot loaders installed on any of your partitions or in your MBR. Furthermore, the partition layout is consistent with what an OEM delivers with Windows pre-installed in EFI mode. Thus, it's unlikely that Windows is booting in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, as you state at the start of your question. I suspect that you've enabled the CSM in your firmware and Windows boots with that enabled, so you've mistakenly assumed that Windows is booting in BIOS mode. That's an unjustified conclusion, for reasons I explain on [this Web page.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) To simplify the boot process, I recommend you disable the CSM (aka "legacy support" or something similar) in your firmware, at least for testing. With it enabled, you throw the dice for boot mode whenever you boot a new device (like an OS installer).

OTOH, Boot Info Script has also failed to turn up evidence of an EFI-mode Windows boot loader. Sometimes it simply fails in this task, for reasons I don't understand; but it's also possible that the files are missing. You may want to look for them "by hand." The most important file is `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` on the ESP -- that is, `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` from Ubuntu.

Your Boot Info Script output indicates that both EFI-mode and BIOS-mode versions of GRUB are installed, and your GRUB configuration file is set to chainload to the (possibly non-existent) EFI-mode Windows boot loader.

Overall, I recommend you try this:

1. Boot to Windows in whatever way you can and disable the *Windows* (not firmware) feature called "Fast Startup," as described [here.](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) This feature, if enabled, causes nothing but trouble on dual-boot configurations, and it could be a cause of at least some of your problems.
2. After this is done, reboot to Windows a couple of times and shut down cleanly. This should get the disks properly unmounted.
3. Try booting to Windows via GRUB. It may begin working at this point, but I can make no promises.
4. If GRUB still can't boot Windows, download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and prepare a boot medium.
5. Boot to the rEFInd medium. It should show options to boot both Windows and Ubuntu. Try them both.
6. If rEFInd boots both your OSes, install its PPA or Debian package version. rEFInd should then take over from GRUB as your primary boot manager.
7. If this fails, you could try [Boot Repair,](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) but I'm skeptical it will help, since I don't see anything obviously wrong with the GRUB configuration, based on your Boot Info Script output, except possibly for a missing Windows boot loader file. Speaking of which....
8. If you find the `bootmgfw.efi` is missing, you can skip all of the above after step #1. Instead, you must re-install the Windows boot loader, which you must do using Windows recovery media. After doing this, you'll probably have to use [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) or `bcdedit` to reset GRUB as the default boot manager.

Comment: Hi Rod, excellent comments and logically followed. Indeed I do have a GPT table type I have the results.txt. I will post it to the pastebin site with the URL.

URL is http://paste.ubuntu.com/13623967/

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me is to start with the  W7 advanced boot options

and use : Disable Driver Signature Enforcement.

afther this, dont shut down your win 7 simply hibernate.

I hope it`ll be useful to you